# Use of Lag /Lead function

Tags: sas

Kindly refer the sample data. I have Month, Region and Values in my data set. I need an Ouput Column as mentioned below. Basically I need on the basis of Month by Values moved ahead. Kindly help.

```
Month   Region  Values  Output
1   R1  2   3
1   R2  4   5
2   R1  3   4
2   R2  5   7
3   R1  4   6
3   R2  7   5
4   R1  6   
4   R2  5
```

Thanks,
Gauraw

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question entirely, could you write out what your intended output for your sample data?

Comment: BTW, I am NOT the one who downvoted you. This seems like a decent question, but what have you tried so far? Stack Overflow usually prefers users to show an attempt to the problem first.

Comment: I'm gonna take a stab at understanding this... you want the Output column to contain the Value for the same region in the next month. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right, you want to assign as OUTCOME the value from the next month within each region. If so, then you can use two SET-statements, the second of which will add the same dataset, but shifted by one record (FIRSTOBS=2).

```
proc sort data=yourdata; by region month; run;

data result;
   set yourdata;
   by region;
   do until(eof);
      set yourdata(firstobs=2 keep=values rename=(values=outcome)) end=eof;
   end;
   if LAST.region then call missing(outcome);
run;
```

And we need to wrap SET into DO UNTIL loop, because otherwise we'll loose the last record of the dataset - the end of the second instance of the same dataset will be reached one record earlier and DATA step will stop.